# Train classifier (natural - NLP) on node.js for unexpected sentences

Tags: node.js, nlp, classification

Some context: Node.js, Bot, [natural module](https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural).

I would like to build a Bot and I am using the natural module in order to parse and overall classify the user input.

```
var classifier = new natural.BayesClassifier();
classifier.addDocument('Hi', 'welcome');
classifier.addDocument('Hello', 'welcome');
classifier.addDocument('Hey', 'welcome');
classifier.addDocument('Good', 'welcome');
...
//back to home
classifier.addDocument('go back to home', 'back2home');
classifier.addDocument('go back home', 'back2home');
classifier.addDocument('return',  'back2home');
classifier.addDocument('return to home', 'back2home');
...
classifier.train();
...
classifier.classify(text);
```

Those tests work fine:

```
  "I would like to go back home" => back2home
  "Hi" => welcome
```

All good, but what if the user text contains something such as: "bla bla bla", I want to get a way to know that the that the text not fits enough in any of the above cases. "bla bla bla" returns me => welcome, but actually i would like it return something such "unknown"/not understood.

It is a way to "train" the classifier in such a way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `getClassifications()` method to get a list of classifications and the associated score, or 'confidence', with it.  From that list you can determine which, if any, it best matches.  Ex:

```js
console.log(classifier.getClassifications('blah blah blah'));
```

Output:

```js
[ { label: 'welcome', value: 0.5 },
  { label: 'back2home', value: 0.5 } ]
```

This example isn't a great one but you can see that it doesn't match any one label very well. The higher the `value` the higher the confidence.

You can check the value of it to ensure that it is above a certain level.  I like to use `0.8` as my check value.  Loop through the results.

```js
const results = classifier.getClassifications('blah blah blah');
let intents = [];

// Check for confidence greater than 8
results.forEach((result) => {
    if(result.value > 0.8) {
        intents.push(result);
    }
});

// Sort intents array by object.value
intents.sort((a,b) => {
    if(a.value < b.value) {
        return -1;
    }
    if(a.value > b.value) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

You now have an array of `intents` with confidence greater than 0.8, sorted descending by their confidence score.

More information at https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural#classifiers
Credit for sorting function [Sort array of objects by string property value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript)

Comment: it looks like the totals for this algorithm always will add up to 1.0, so if you you only have two categories you're forcing it to make a choice. Add more than N categories, and then a 1/N confidence threshold should give valuable results. Also note that natural.Bayes doesn't use word vectors so you won't get any semantic interpolation.